# Menu icon on ActionBar of ListActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, menubar, android-menu

I want my refresh item to appear on the top bar. I am extending `ListActivity` and using the theme `android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar`. The menu is created using:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="eu.pcas_project.client.android.pa.services.ServiceList">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/refresh_all_services"
        android:title="@string/refresh_all_services"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_service_list, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

[image: ListActivity with misplaced menu icon.]

If I change `app:showAsAction="always"` on the menu XML to `android:showAsAction="always"`, this works as I want it to—icon on top bar—but then I get an error saying *Should use android:showAsAction when not using the appcompat library*. Can it be fixed?

Targeting API 19.

Comment: The warning is correct: if your activity is not extended from `AppCompatActivity`, you can use `android:` schema prefix in the menu xml. But, if you extends from `AppCompatActivity`, you must use anything other than `android:` schema prefix to help the assembler recognizes `AppCompat` menu features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the question, `android:showAsAction="always"` works but generates an error.

While the project was not using the appcompat library directly, I discovered that a library imported by said project had `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XXX.YYY.ZZZ` as a dependency even though it was not needed. This was added by Android Studio. Once the line was removed and the project rebuilt the error disappeared and the refresh icon appeared on the top right corner instead of on the menu.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you hav a physical button for menu it doesn't appear. but you can try this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/refresh_all_services"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    android:title="@string/refresh_all_services"
    app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ActionProvider"
    />
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. Yes, there is a menu button but I tried with a phone with dedicated menu button and it still does not work (this time appears as three dots on top corner).